# Search by child product when search by sku in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some products below

```
Id Name SKU isParent
1   A   100   True
2   A1  101   False
3   A2  102   False
4   A3  103   False
5   A4  104   False
6   B   105   True
7   B1  106   False
8   B2  107   False
```

I have query to find the product by name,SKU.

I want to exclude the product which is IsParent is false when try to search by name but when its exact search by sku then all product need to be search. How to do it?

Search by name is working fine with excluding isParent false products.

My elastic query as below

```
{
  "min_score": 810,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Published": {
              "value": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "Stores.Id": [
              0,
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "IsParentProduct": "false"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 100
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 150
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ProductCategories.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ProductCategories.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 300
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ParentCategory.Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 1000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ParentCategory.Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 750
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ShortDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ShortDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "FullDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "FullDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ProductManufacturer.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ProductManufacturer.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "ProductPromoTags",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.Name": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.Name": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.SystemName": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.SystemName": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "Sku": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 500
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "Sku": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 100
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "SpecificationAttributes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name.exact": {
                              "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                              "boost": 80
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name.exact": {
                              "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                              "boost": 100
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 32,
  "aggs": {
    "PriceRanges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "FinalPrice",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "0",
            "to": "100"
          },
          {
            "from": "101",
            "to": "998"
          },
          {
            "from": "999",
            "to": "1999"
          },
          {
            "from": "2000",
            "to": "2999"
          },
          {
            "from": "3000"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "ProductCategoryCustomURL": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ProductCategories.CustomURL",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "ProductManufacturer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ProductManufacturer.Name",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "SpecificationAttributesfiltered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SpecificationAttributes": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "SpecificationAttributes"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "Spec_group": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "SpecificationAttributes.Name",
                "size": 100
              },
              "aggs": {
                "Opctions": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name",
                    "size": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "SpecificationAttributesFirstFiltered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SpecificationAttributes": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "SpecificationAttributes"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "Spec_group": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "SpecificationAttributes.Name",
                "size": 100
              },
              "aggs": {
                "Opctions": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name",
                    "size": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Main image is parent product.
After image you can see the three round image and sequre box that are separate products that connect with main image product. Child products haveing  property "IsChildProduct" that is set as true if its child.

I want to exclude the child products in search as separate product that is working fine in my query. but if user want to search by child product sku,name etc then my query return emty result.

Let me know what should I do to make this working.

Comment: You should show the query you have so far

Answer (score 0):

You should share the query you have so far, but here is my take. Basically, one of the should clause must match, either by `Name` with `isParent: false` or just by `SKU`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "isParent": false
              }
            },
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Name": "xyz_search_term"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "Sku": "xyz_search_term"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "isParent": false
              }
            },
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 100
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 150
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ProductCategories.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ProductCategories.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 300
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ParentCategory.Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 1000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ParentCategory.Name": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 750
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ShortDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ShortDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "FullDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "FullDescription": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 5
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ProductManufacturer.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "ProductManufacturer.Name.exact": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 200
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "ProductPromoTags",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.Name": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.Name": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.SystemName": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "ProductPromoTags.SystemName": {
                                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                                    "boost": 100
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "SpecificationAttributes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name.exact": {
                              "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                              "boost": 80
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "SpecificationAttributes.SpecificationAttributeOptions.Name.exact": {
                              "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                              "boost": 100
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Sku": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 500
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "Sku": {
                    "query": "BGEBASIC33",
                    "boost": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated query into description

Comment: Please see if my query makes sense

Comment: Can you please made your changes into my query and repost it here?

Comment: there's no Name or SKU constraint in your query

Comment: I have update my actual query. Please help me on it

Comment: I've updated my query according to yours (just the query part, not aggregations)

Comment: No. It's not worked